# Digitalsignature verification failed using Mimekit

Tags: c#, cryptography, smime, mimekit, mime-mail

We are trying to use MimeKit to validate the digitally signed emails(.p7m) signature. When I call `signature.Verify();` it is throwing the error message:

> {"Failed to verify digital signature: non-empty set
>   required\r\nParameter name: value"}.

But the same mail was verified successfully by Limilabs.Mail.

I am using the below code to verify the signature.

```cs
if (message.Body is MultipartSigned)
{
    var signed = (MultipartSigned)message.Body;
    foreach (var signature in signed.Verify())
    {
        try
        {
            bool valid = signature.Verify();

            // If valid is true, then it signifies that the signed content
            // has not been modified since this particular signer signed the
            // content.
            // However, if it is false, then it indicates that the signed
            // content has been modified.
        }
        catch (DigitalSignatureVerifyException)
        {
            // There was an error verifying the signature.
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone can help me on this why I am getting the error?

Comment: With security there are lots of options.  You may have an issue with 32 vs 64 bit encryption mode.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: There's more to an exception than just the `Message` property. What is the type of exception? What is the `StackTrace`? What is the InnerException type/message/stacktrace?

Comment: Which type of SecureMimeContext did you register as your default? WindowsSecureMimeContext? Or is it DefaultSecureMimeContext? Or something else?

Comment: I am getting DigitalSignatureVerifyException and the inner exception is System.ArgumentException. Inner exception message is "non-empty set required\r\nParameter name: value"

Comment: stack trace --   at Org.BouncyCastle.Pkix.PkixParameters.SetTrustAnchors(ISet tas)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Pkix.PkixParameters..ctor(ISet trustAnchors)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Pkix.PkixBuilderParameters..ctor(ISet trustAnchors, IX509Selector targetConstraints)
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.BuildCertPath(HashSet anchors, IX509Store certificates, IX509Store crls, X509Certificate certificate, DateTime signingTime)
   at MimeKit.Cryptography.BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext.<GetDigitalSignaturesAsync>d__29.MoveNext()

Comment: Have you imported any trust anchors in to your SecureMimeContext? That seems like the problem. MimeKit does not ship with any CA Root certificates, so it will have 0 Trust Anchors to start out. You need to import some or else use a different SecureMimeContext as the default (such as WindowsSecureMimeContext if you are running on .NETFramework on Windows).

Comment: CryptographyContext.Register (typeof (WindowsSecureMimeContext));

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that MimeKit, by default, uses the `DefaultSecureMimeContext` backend for S/MIME when the developer hasn't explicitly provided a context for use in the `MultipartSigned.Verify()` method invocation and also hasn't registered an alternative S/MIME context using `CryptographyContext.Register()`.

Since the `DefaultSecureMimeContext` starts off with an empty database of S/MIME certificates, it has no trusted anchors (aka Root Certificate Authority certificates) and thus throws the exception you are seeing when it goes to build a certificate chain for the S/MIME signer when verifying the signature.

You can fix this either by importing some Root Certificate Authority certificates (preferably including the one needed in order to build the certificate chain for said signer) -or- by using the `WindowsSecureMimeContext`:

```
if (message.Body is MultipartSigned)
{
    var signed = (MultipartSigned)message.Body;

    using (var ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext ()) {
        foreach (var signature in signed.Verify(ctx))
        {
            try
            {
                bool valid = signature.Verify();

                // If valid is true, then it signifies that the signed content
                // has not been modified since this particular signer signed the
                // content.
                // However, if it is false, then it indicates that the signed
                // content has been modified.
            }
            catch (DigitalSignatureVerifyException)
            {
                // There was an error verifying the signature.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jstedfast, Thanks for the answer. It is working fine after adding WindowsSecureMimeContext.

Comment: Glad it worked fr you. Would you mind clicking to "accept" my answer? It will help other users see that the solution works without having to read the comments. Thanks!